# AWS and Datagrip creating java.net.unknownhost exception

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, intellij-datagrip

I am trying to set up an AWS account that worked smoothly, then copying the RDS data for the PostgreSQL server into JetBrains Datagrip IDE and when I clicked test connection. I get an error.

"[08001] The connection attempt failed. java.net.UnknownHostException: database-1.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2."

The 'name' field in Datagrip was auto-populated from Host: which I copied from the endpoint.

The 'port' was saved as standard '5432'

The 'user' field came from AWS field Master username under the 'configuration tab'

The 'password' field I set and wrote down in my backup notebook.

The 'URL:' field is showing jdbc:postgresql://database-1.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2:5432/postgres-1

My driver in Datagrip is showing PostgreSQL and connection type is listed as default.

AWS is not the easiest online platform for SQL but I was able to get this far in about 12 minutes whereas Azure spent an hour and a half just jerking me around with stupid info.

It feels like I am missing something simple.

When I enter "ping -a database-1.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" into my mac bash CLI I get Request timeout for icmp_seq 0, then Request timeout for icmp_seq 1... so does that mean the IPv4 isn't active even though AWS says it is?

I'm relatively new to online storage, so thanks in advance for your help.

I am following this tutorial for the AWS vs PostgreSQL, but in this tutorial, he references Mysql so I just clicked Postgres instead of MySQL.

https://medium.com/cory-mayfield/linking-amazon-rds-with-jetbrains-datagrip-d5cc0e2f44f4

Comment: Depending on how you configured the ports on your AWS instance, you may or may not be able to ping the host. Likewise, depending on how you configured your instance, you may or may not be able to connect to the database via port 5432 -- can you confirm you opened those ports?

Comment: I never made changes to any ports, and only changed the password to something other than the default then made the instance publicly accessible. I created the AWS account, started the instance and waited for it to run.

Tomorrow I'm going to rerun this tutorial and see what I missed. https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/


Is there a way to create a terminal within RDS that will give me error codes, It's been a long day filled with algorithms, algebra and trying to get this database running and I can't think of the term for python errors.

Comment: If you're using RDS, you can't open a terminal to get the info.  Have you tried using a client (like `psql` or `pgAdmin4`) to connect to the database?

Comment: No, I haven't, I thought that if the IP address for the server was not giving pings to the outside that there was a block or something preventing access. I'll try pgpadmin but how will that generate a different result than what datagrip does? Do you recommend or have additional resources for me to troubleshoot an AWS RDS server?

Comment: You're right--Datagrip should be good enough.  Sorry, I got this mixed up with another issue.  Have you tried logging in to your AWS console and just get the IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: The ip address they gave me is here, I've never used the AWS console. Is this an internal "terminal" like program or is console just what the AWS interface is called. I've been doing this in my bash terminal "ping -a 172.31.0.0/16" and it says that ping: cannot resolve 172.31.0.0/16"

Comment: The console is the operating web-interface for AWS, I was tired when I sent that.

Comment: @richyen I was able to get a green light after pressing "Test Connection" so It shows. This was possible after finding a tutorial online about Mac/AWS setup with Azure, it came down to adding my IP and my Routers IP as white listed, plus changing the "publicly available" to yes.